# Regarding the ebpf question, bpf_ringbuf_submit is not in effect

Tags: linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf

Why does the user-mode callback function fail to respond to a successful call to kernel mode bpf_ringbuf_submit(data, 0)? but the user-mode callback function responds successfully when the parameter is changed to bpf_ringbuf_submit(data, 2),thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That second argument is a flag to determine if/when notifications for new data are sent. From [the helpers man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html):

```
void bpf_ringbuf_submit(void *data, u64 flags)

    Description
        Submit reserved ring buffer sample, pointed to by
        data.  If BPF_RB_NO_WAKEUP is specified in flags,
        no notification of new data availability is sent.
        If BPF_RB_FORCE_WAKEUP is specified in flags,
        notification of new data availability is sent
        unconditionally.
```

Value 2 is `BPF_RB_FORCE_WAKEUP` and forces the notification.

---

**Behavior of each flag**

We can find the logic for the different flag in [`bpf_ringbuf_commit()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0.6/source/kernel/bpf/ringbuf.c#L370):

- `BPF_RB_FORCE_WAKEUP` (2): The consumer is immediately notified by `bpf_ringbuf_commit()`. There is no batching.
- `BPF_RB_NO_WAKEUP` (1): The consumer is never notified by `bpf_ringbuf_commit()`.
- default (0): The consumer is notified if it already caught up on past events shared on the ring buffer. If it didn't yet consume the previous batch of events, it won't be notified. This is sometimes referred to as *adaptive notifications* or *adaptive batching*.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but I'm more interested in knowing why my callback function can receive data in some cases and can't receive data in some cases when the second parameter is 0, and how this parameter 0 determines whether to notify or not.

Comment: I've extended my answer to describe the different behaviors. Hope it helps.